# Prepared statement returns same result during 'while'

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out why this `while` statement returns the same account ID each time. Below is the function I am using:

```
    function Hourly(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id IN(SELECT uid FROM point WHERE zoneid=1)";
        $arr = array();
        $user = $this->database->DBQry($sql, $arr);
        $id = $user[0]['ID'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM point WHERE zoneid > -1";
        $arr = array();
        $row = $this->database->DBCtr($sql, $arr);
        $i=0;
        while($i < $row){
            $arr = array(":userid" => $id, ":zoneid" => 1, ":cash" => 500);
            $this->database->DBIns($arr, 'cashtable');
            echo"$id DONE!<br>";
            $i++;
        }
    }
```

Here are my prepared statements I'm using.

```
// Query
    function DBQry($sql,$arr){
        $sth = $this->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $sth->execute($arr);
        $rs = $sth->fetchAll();
        return $rs;
    }

    // Count
    function DBCtr($sql,$arr){
        $sth = self::prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $sth->execute($arr);
        return $sth->rowCount();
    }
```

I think the issue I am encountering is with one of the statements.

What I am trying to achieve from the function is a result like this:

```
64 DONE!
80 DONE!
124 DONE!
648 DONE!
984 DONE!
1341 DONE!
1468 DONE!
1887 DONE!
2017 DONE!
2193 DONE!
2267 DONE!
```

But this is what comes out of the function:

```
64 DONE!
64 DONE!
64 DONE!
64 DONE!
64 DONE!
64 DONE!
64 DONE!
64 DONE!
64 DONE!
64 DONE!
64 DONE!
```

---

**Code I am working from**

```
<?
$DBHost = "localhost";  
$DBUser = "user";
$DBPassword = "password";
$DBName = "db";
$Hcash=50;
$Link = MySQL_Connect($DBHost, $DBUser, $DBPassword) or die ("Can't connect to MySQL");
MySQL_Select_Db($DBName, $Link) or die ("Database ".$DBName." does not exist.");

$OnlineAccountQuery = Mysql_Query("SELECT * FROM point WHERE zoneid > -1");
$OnlineAccountNum = Mysql_Num_Rows($OnlineAccountQuery);

$i=0;
WHILE($i < $OnlineAccountNum){
$OnlineAccountArray = Mysql_Fetch_Array($OnlineAccountQuery);
$UID = $OnlineAccountArray['uid'];
MySQL_Query("INSERT INTO cashtable (userid, zoneid, cash) VALUES ($UID, 1, $Hcash)");
echo"$UID DONE!<br>";
$i++;
}
?>
```

---

**Response to Shivan Raptor's Answer**

```
function Hourly(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM point WHERE zoneid > -1";
        $arr = array();
        $row = $this->database->DBCtr($sql, $arr);
        $i=0;
        while($i < $row){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id IN(SELECT uid FROM point WHERE zoneid=1)";
            $arr = array();
            $user = $this->database->DBQry($sql, $arr);
            $id = $user[0]['ID'];
            $arr = array(":userid" => $id, ":zoneid" => 1, ":cash" => 500);
            $this->database->DBIns($arr, 'cashtable');
            echo"$id DONE!<br>";
            $i++;
        }
    }
```

---

**Table Structures**

```
 CREATE TABLE `point` (
`uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`aid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`zoneid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`zonelocalid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`accountstart` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`lastlogin` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`enddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`uid`,`aid`),
 KEY `IX_point_aidzoneid` (`aid`,`zoneid`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 CREATE TABLE `cashtable` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `zoneid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cash` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: $id is defined outside the while, and never changed inside, so its always the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't overwrite `$id`. It's defined once before the while loop.

Please double check your logic.

---

**UPDATE after question edit:**

In your response's `Hourly()` function, `$row` should contain the count of rows of the first `$sql`. However, in the `while` loop, you're querying the 2nd same `$sql` again & again. Therefore, `$id` is always the same.

I think your 2nd query should relate to the result of first query, but you didn't. Consider joining 2 queries if possible.

Comment: could you show an example? I have edited my OP with what I would have thought you meant, but that returned the same result as well. And the `echo "$id DONE!";` is just to see the results.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. Could it be the prepared statements I am using?

Comment: No. It's a logic issue. The 2nd query doesn't change in every while loop. It should be changed.

Comment: I don't know your table structure, thus I can't give example of your updated query. Question: How does two queries relate?

Comment: Updated OP with table structures.

Comment: Hey, you should at least try it yourself, and explain the information posted. How does these two tables relate? by `zoneid` ?

Comment: `zoneid` is weather or not the account is logged in on the server. I got the Hourly problem fixed, I used a `Foreach` instead of a `while`. But I have another problem with a different function that still uses a `while` statement. I really hate posting questions that I really want to figure out myself, but I am really stumped on this one.

Comment: `while` and `foreach` statement work in a similar way. Ask your new question in a separate SO question. And be sure to mark the answer correct.